# Python - Replace a given percentage (%) of characters (randomly) in a String?

Tags: python, string, random, replace

I have a string e.g.

```
x = "aaaaaaaaaa"
```

I would like to replace e.g. 20% of the "a" with "b" . I tried:

```
x_new = ''.join(i if random.randint(0, 1) else 'b' for i in x)
```

but with `random.randint(0,1)` I do not know how to get e.g. 20% replacement.

Comment: strings length * 0.2 is the number you need to replace?.. What should happen for an odd number length string in this case?

Comment: 20% is the same as 1 in 5 ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code keeps the original `a` character with probability 80%, otherwise, it replaces it with `b`

```
from random import random
x = "aaaaaaaaaa"
rand_replace = lambda c: c if random()<0.8 and c=='a' else 'b'
x_new = ''.join([rand_replace(c) for c in x])
```

And If you want the total probability of a replacement to be 20% stringwise:

```
rand_replace = lambda c: c if random()<0.8**(1.0/len(x)) and c=='a' else 'b'
```

Comment: @ Uri Goren:Many thanks for the complete and quick answer.

Comment: @Lily - you can accept it if you believe it fully addresses your question.

Comment: This does not make a 20% replacement. The probability distribution is not uniform like you've stated

Comment: If the OP want to replace each char independently (as her solution suggests) then the code should remain unchanged, if the OP desires the total probability of a change in the entire string to be 20%, then `0.8` should be replaced with `(1-0.2)**(len(x))`

Comment: @ Uri Goren: Thank you a lot. I wanted  the total probability of a change in the entire string to be 20%.

Comment: @Lilly Then you should apply the modification Uri made in the comments. And don't forget to accept

Answer (score 0):

```
x = "aaaaaaaaaa"
x_new = x.replace('a', 'b', int(len(x) * 0.2) )
print x_new
```

Comment: @ Uri Goren: Thanks, but I have the impression that in the new version of the code the first 2 letters are replaced each time (i.e. not randomly).

Comment: This is @balakumaran.g 's answer, I've simply formatted it as code

Comment: @ balakumaran.g: Thanks, but the Uri Goren’s code (with the change mentioned in the comment) suits better for my purpose.